# How to get data from array in object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I can't seem to get specific data from an array inside an object.

`$this->fields->adres` gets the address correctly, but i can't get a level deeper.

I've tried:

```
$this->fields->province
$this->fields->province->0
$this->fields->province[0]
```

And: (edit)

```
$this->fields["province"][0]
$this->fields['province'][0]
$this->data->fields['province'][0]
```

But it does not return anything while it should return "Flevoland".

First part of the object print_r($this, TRUE) below:

```
RSMembershipModelSubscribe Object
(
    [_id] => 2
    [_extras] => Array
        (
        )

    [_data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => testzz
            [name] => testzz
            [email] => xxxx@example.com
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [province] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Flevoland
                        )

                    [plaats] => tesdt
                    [adres] => test
```

Comment: be consistent in language. Use 'city' and 'address' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see by your output, object members are likely to be private (if you follow conventions, anyway you must prepend an underscore while calling them), so you're calling them the wrong way;
This code works:

```
$this->_data->fields['province'][0];
```

You can see it in action [here](http://codepad.org/laojsTgi);
I created a similar object, and using

```
$membership = new RSMembershipModelSubscribe();
echo $membership->_data->fields['province'][0];
```

outputs "Flevoland" as expected.

Comment: You were almost there, @Antoon :). Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" (the tick mark under the vote count) for future references; glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use type casting.

```
$fields = (array) $this->data->fields;
echo $fields['province'][0];
```

Comment: Was going to mention this :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_data->fields['province'][0]
```

Comment: unfortunately not. Fields is an array

Comment: fixed it sec before comment -_-

Comment: Thanks for your quick response guys, unfortunately, none of them gave back any result.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As fields is already an array, try this:

```
$this->fields['province'][0]
```

This assuming the [_data] object is `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

Fields and province are both arrays, you should be trying `$this->fields["province"][0]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response guys, unfortunately, none of them gave back any result.. any other suggestions?

Comment: That really should have done it.  Can you do a print_r on $this directly before running this line of code, then run it after?  I'm suspecting there may be a different problem.