# Wordpress Plugin - PHP Multidimensional Array (Find key by specific value)

Tags: php, arrays

These multi-dimensional arrays are giving me a headache. Here's the array, and I'm trying to pull just the [asin] value. This is from a Wordpress plugin, and here's how I dumped the array:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($this);
print "</pre>";
```

*output:

```
THEPLUGIN_Template_Handler Object
(
[inline:THEPLUGIN_Template_Handler:private] => 
[is_widget:THEPLUGIN_Template_Handler:private] => 
[timestamp_template:THEPLUGIN_Template_Handler:private] => 0
[store] => 
[atts] => Array
    (
        [template] => widget-vertical-custom
        [star_rating_size] => large
        [image_size] => large
    )

[type] => box
[items] => Array
    (
        [B009FUF6DM] => Array
            (
                [id] => 18
                [status] => active
                [asin] => B009FUF6DM
....
```

I tried:

```
    echo $this->items[0];
    echo $this->items[0][0];
    echo $this['items'][0];
    echo $this['items']['B009FUF6DM']['asin'];
    echo $this->items['B009FUF6DM']['asin'];
```

To clarify, if I use this code `echo $this->items['B009FUF6DM']['asin'];` it does display the ASIN, but the problem is that the 'B009FUF6DM' value changes. So I need to account for that by just accessing the [0] index of that array, or something.

Similar to 
[How to get data from array in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933029/how-to-get-data-from-array-in-object)
and 
[PHP Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value)

Thanks for any help or direction! :)

Answer (score 0):

The top level is an object, so to access items you need to access it as an attribute.

```
$this->items['B009FUF6DM']['asin'];
```

From somewhere else, if the attribute is private you need to provide a public getter for the attribute.

Comment: this helps, but my issue is that the asin value changes. If I enter this code: `echo $this->items['B009FUF6DM']['asin'];` it does display the asin, `B009FUF6DM`, but I need to access like the [0] index for that array, something like: `echo $this['items'][0]['asin'];`

Comment: You asked about reaching that element based on the the print_r(). Now you are asking something different. I suggest you open another question and provide the information relevant to this other matter.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that :) sorry for the confusion