# Get php array from object

Tags: php, object

i am not able to get array from object:

please see my code below:

```
 print_r($product_ser_id);
```

Print result:

```
WHMCS\Service\Service Object
(
    [table:protected] => tblhosting
    [columnMap:protected] => Array
        (
            [clientId] => userid
            [productId] => packageid
            [serverId] => server
            [registrationDate] => regdate
            [paymentGateway] => paymentmethod
            [status] => domainstatus
            [promotionId] => promoid
            [overrideAutoSuspend] => overideautosuspend
            [overrideSuspendUntilDate] => overidesuspenduntil
            [bandwidthUsage] => bwusage
            [bandwidthLimit] => bwlimit
            [lastUpdateDate] => lastupdate
            [firstPaymentAmount] => firstpaymentamount
            [recurringAmount] => amount
            [recurringFee] => amount
        )
}
```

here i have to get value from `[productId]`

i have already tested as: `$product_ser_id -> attributes:protected;`

its show error as:

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
```

and i know there many example so please don't tell duplicate untill you really understand my issues.

Please help

thanks

Comment: Don't you have any getters ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from array in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933029/how-to-get-data-from-array-in-object)

Comment: Without extending WHMCS\Service\Service or changing WHMCS\Service\Service class you won't be able to get that array because its protected. You could create an adapter and extend the Service, and then create a method that returns it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124676/how-to-retrieve-variable-from-object

Comment: @CésarFerreira please help, mostly peoples are saying duplicate without  understand protected

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy its protect so its not duplicate

Comment: Is that map hard baked into the class?  If it is you could just extend and write your own getter (if that is there isn't already a method to do so).

Comment: Here are some filthy hacks if you really must: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php

Comment: @Progrock your suggested hack worked: stackoverflow.com/a/28352585/2384642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issues solved with the answer of @[drewish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203673/drewish)

Source: [ReflectionClass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352585/2384642)

Code:

```
 function accessProtected($obj, $prop) {
  $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
  $property = $reflection->getProperty($prop);
  $property->setAccessible(true);
  return $property->getValue($obj);
}
```