# how to retrieve variable from object

Tags: php

I want to retrieve $se_module value from my object. How can I get that? I can easily get others by $object->Owner->name. I've tried $object->{$se_module}, but got error as undefined variable.

`stdClass Object
(
    [Owner] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Merv Henry
            [id] => 2880896000003943001
        )`

```
[Modified_Time] => 2019-01-09T21:25:05-05:00
[$attachments] => 
[Created_Time] => 2019-01-09T21:25:05-05:00
[Parent_Id] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 
        [id] => 2880896000011553097
    )

[$editable] => 1
[$se_module] => Deals
[Modified_By] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Merv Henry
        [id] => 2880896000003943001
    )

[$size] => 
[$voice_note] => 
[id] => 2880896000011676081
[Created_By] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Merv Henry
        [id] => 2880896000003943001
    )

[Note_Title] => 
[Note_Content] => This unit needs 1@ DA97-12540K & 1@ DA97-13718C
```

Quote is needed
)

Comment: So you are using a property name that starts with a $ sign here, or what? Weird thing to do IMHO, but the correct syntax to access this should be `$object->{'$se_module'}` then - you want `$se_module` to be interpreted as a text literal here, and not as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

you cane make it as array then you can get it

```
$data = (array)$se_module;
```

then can get data like this

`$data['Modified_Time'];`